# Running python function in bash - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, bash, function, loops, recursion

I am trying to call a custom python function from bash to create input files and populate them with randomly generated DNA sequences. My python code to generate the sequences looks like this:

```
def getsequence(filename, length):
  bases=["A","G","C","T"]
  sequence=""
  for i in range(length):
    sequence+=choice(bases)
  output = filename + ".seq"
  my_file=open(output, "w")
  my_file.write(getsequence(filename, 1000))
  my_file.close()
  return sequence
```

And the bash code is:

```
for i in $(seq -f %03g 1 5)
do
  filename="DNAsequence$i"
  python -c "import DNAgenforbash;DNAgenforbash.getsequence('$filename', 1000)"
done
```

This works great to create the files, however no matter how i adjust the code they are empty and i get the error RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object. I have tried adjusting my for loop to contain the output commands as well, as well as I have tried increasing the recursion limit but i continue to get this error. Any tips on how to fix?

I am currently only testing this with 5 files, but will need to do 100 total.

Thank you!!

Comment: The line `my_file.write(getsequence(filename, 1000))` makes an unconditional recursive call to `getsequence`, so this is infinite recursion.

Comment: Looks like you copied this from somewhere without understanding the parts. The lines between `output = "..."` and `my_file.close()` should apparently be outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

@joanis and @Sylvester Kruin thank you for helping me figure this out so quickly! I changed the code so I was no longer calling the function within itself and rather calling the actual sequence output:

```
def getsequence(filename, length):
  bases=["A","G","C","T"]
  sequence=""
  for i in range(length):
    sequence+=choice(bases)
  output = filename + ".seq"
  my_file=open(output, "w")
  my_file.write(sequence)
  my_file.close()
  return sequence
```

This seems to work well and I no longer get any recursion errors. Thank you for your help!